# Which desktop computer should I choose (smaller SSD storage with lower RAM vs higher HDD storage with higher RAM)?

Tags: memory, hard-disk, desktop, data-storage

I want to get a new desktop computer. I don't plan on using it play games. It is mostly to do work at home (running python code for analysis, looking through sometimes large excel files, having music play in the background).

Through my research, I found that it is probably most economical to buy an out of the box desktop (instead of buying a custom one or building my own)

In terms of specs, I followed the advice from [this article](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-much-ram) and it seems like having at least 8gb of RAM would be ideal.

I ended up narrowing my choice to [two models from Acer](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/compare/DT.BAPAA.012-DT.BAPAA.004) that seem good. Basically the two options I am deciding between are (the processor and other specs are identical):

(1) 512GB SSD with 8GB RAM - Costs 650

(2) 2TB HDD with 12GB RAM - Costs 550

From my research, I say quite a few articles saying that SSD are faster than HDD, but I am having trouble deciding which spec to go with (or if you know of a better deal to accomplish my goal). Thanks

Comment: Depends on the specs of the drives. Lower speeds on the SSD might make the larger HDDs seem like a better choice.

Comment: I would suggest going rather with the SSD+8GB-RAM. 8 GB RAM is very decent, and an SSD is a very basic noticeable upgrade.